# Default parameter behaviour of a class in an object

Tags: kotlin

```
object M {
    class C (val x: Int, val y: Int = 5)
}

class N(val x: Int, val y: Int = 5)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = N(3)
    val q = (M::C)(3)
}
```

Why is there a syntax error in the `val q =` line ?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `::` is to use [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) in kotlin and that's why it's showing you syntax error as to perform that you need to pass two arguments.
So in that case your syntax must be

`val q = (M::C)(3,5)`

If you want just want object of C class than you should do it like

```
val q = M.C(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin doesn't have namespaces like C++. Packages or nested classes are sperated throught `.` instead of `::`. You can simply replace this line with:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = N(3)
    val q = M.C(3)
}
```